# Remove nested html tags in php

Tags: php, html, nested, tags

Is there a method to remove all nested html tags from a string except parent tags in php?

Example:

Input:

> This <pre>is a <b>pen</b> and I like
>   <i>it!</i></pre> Good <a>morning
>   <pre>Mary</pre>!</a> Bye.

Output:

> This <pre>is a pen and I like it!</pre> Good
>   <a>morning Mary!</a> Bye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a simple code that maybe work for you, I used the class [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/es/class.domdocument.php)  to parse the HTML string and get the main childNodes:

```
//Your HTML
$html = 'This <pre>is a <b>pen</b> and I like <i>it!</i></pre> Good <a>morning <pre>Mary</pre>!</a> Bye.';

$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHtml("<body>{$html}</body>");

$nodes = iterator_to_array($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes);

$nodesFinal = implode(
    array_map(function($node) {
        if ($node->nodeName === '#text') {
            return $node->textContent;
        }
        return sprintf('<%1$s>%2$s</%1$s>', $node->nodeName, $node->textContent);
    }, $nodes)
);

echo $nodesFinal;
```

Show me:

```
This <pre>is a pen and I like it!</pre> Good <a>morning Mary!</a> Bye.
```

### Edit

In the next code I get solution for get the attrs in the tags and for UTF8 encoding in the html string:

```
//Your HTML
$html = '<a href="https://sample.com" target="_blank">Test simple <span>hyperlink.</span></a> This is a text. <div class="info class2">Simple div. <b>A value bold!</b>.</div> End with a some váúlé...';


$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHtml("<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'/><body>{$html}</body>");

$nodes = iterator_to_array($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes);

$nodesFinal = implode(
    array_map(function($node) {
        $textContent = $node->nodeValue;
        if ($node->nodeName === '#text') {
            return $textContent;
        }
        $attr = implode(' ', array_map(function($attr) {
            return sprintf('%s="%s"', $attr->name, $attr->value);
        }, iterator_to_array($node->attributes)));

        return sprintf('<%1$s %3$s>%2$s</%1$s>', $node->nodeName, $textContent, $attr);
    }, $nodes)
);

echo $nodesFinal;
```

Show me:

```
<a href="https://sample.com" target="_blank">Test simple hyperlink.</a> This is a text. <div class="info class2">Simple div. A value bold!.</div> End with a some váúlé...
```

I used the `meta` tag for set the encoding and the property named `attributes` of the object [DOMNode](http://php.net/manual/es/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.attributes)